# getting character count on specific # of lines

Tags: linux

I am new to linux. I am trying to get the character count of a specific amount of lines. For example, I have a test file (alphabet.txt) that has 26 lines- each line with a different letter of the alphabet.

I was wondering if it was possible to get the character count for a specific amount of lines. For instance, if I wanted to get the character count from  lines 1-5 (inclusive)

I was thinking of something like this

head -1 | tail -5 longSeq.txt wc -c
or this
wc -c head -1 | tail -5 longSeq.txt

However, I cannot seem to get the right order

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's a hundred ways to stroke that cat ...

How about this one?

```
sed -n 1,5p alphabet.txt | tr -d '\n' | wc -c
```

Using `sed`, `-n` suppresses normal output, `1,5p` forcibly prints lines 1 through 5 ... `tr` strips the newlines.

Comment: `wc` would also count the carriage return. `awk '{s+=length($0)} END {print s}'` might be what he need.

Comment: Good point. See amendment.

Comment: thank you! works for me!

Comment: Welcome @candrews33 - feel free to accept the answer if this works for you :)